# react js datepicker maxDate handling if date value is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not sure how to handle a passed in prop dateValue to a component with a React DatePicker, so far this is working

```
<DatePicker
  onChange={this.handleOnChange}
   selected={myDateValue}
  maxDate={this.props.maximumDate}
/>

How do I handle if maximumDate is null? The desired outcome would be like DatePicker without a maxDate attribute and the datePicker can navigate to unlimited future. Basically, how do I handle if this.props.maximumDate === null?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `DatePicker` to act as if the maxDate prop isn't set, you can pass `undefined` instead of `null`

Example using ternary operator:

`maxDate={(this.props.maximumDate === null) ? undefined : this.props.maximumDate}`